# Renaming xarray variable reverts to old variable when writing to netcdf

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to rename a variable in some netcdf files. I am able to accomplish this using `xr.Dataset.rename()`. However, when I write that out to a netcdf file it has the old variable name that I was trying to replace. Here is the output from the original:

```
xr.open_dataset('/Volumes/Ext HDD 1/Python_data/crop_means/argentinacorn_tp_mean.nc')
```

[image]

```
#rename and save files
import glob
import xarray as xr
precip_files=glob.glob('/Volumes/Ext HDD 1/Python_data/crop_means/*tp*.nc')

for i in precip_files:

    data=xr.open_dataset(i)
    data2=data.rename_vars(name_dict={'tp_mean':'total_precip'})
    data2.to_netcdf('/Volumes/Ext HDD 1/Python_data/crop_means2/'+i.split('/')[-1].split('_'). 
    [0]+'_total_precip_mean.nc')
```

When loading in one of the new files this is the output:

```
xr.open_dataset('/Volumes/Ext HDD 1/Python_data/crop_means2/argentinacorn_total_precip_mean.nc')
```

[image]

They are exactly the same. If I just run the code without writing it out, this is what outputs:

```
data=xr.open_dataset('/Volumes/Ext HDD 1/Python_data/crop_means/argentinacorn_tp_mean.nc')
data=data.rename_vars(name_dict={'tp_mean':'total_precip'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.rename` instead of `data.rename_vars` will solve this issue.

```
    data2=data.rename(name_dict={'tp_mean':'total_precip'})
    data2.to_netcdf(...)
```